# Java Number Sequence Generator Not Working

Tags: java, numbers, sequence

Having trouble with this code that am I writing.  The purpose of the code is to formulate modifiers for a number sequence and then give the first 10 numbers in that sequence.  However, something appears to be wrong with my loop mechanism because it is printing out an infinite amount of values when it should only be doing 10.  I plan on including the division and power functions to the code, but ran into this problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PatternCreator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out
            .println("Please enter the starting value of the number sequence.");
    double sequence = s.nextInt();
    System.out
            .println("Please enter the addition/subtraction modifier; e.g. 2,-2.");
    double addsub = s.nextInt();
    System.out
            .println("Please enter the multiplication modifier; 0 for none.");
    double mult = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the division modifier; 0 for none.");
    double divi = s.nextInt();
    System.out
            .println("Please enter the exponential modifier; 0 for none.");
    double power = s.nextInt();

    double addonly = sequence + addsub;

    while (mult == 0 && divi == 0 && power == 0) {
        for (int count1 = 1; count1 <= 10; count1++) {
            if (count1 == 1) {
                System.out.print(sequence + " ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(addonly + " ");
                addonly = addonly + addsub;
            }
        }
    }

    double multadd = sequence + addsub * mult;

    while (mult != 0 && divi == 0 && power == 0) {
        for (int count2 = 1; count2 <= 10; count2++) {
            if (count2 == 1) {
                System.out.print(sequence + " ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(multadd + " ");
                multadd += multadd;
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `mult`, `divi`, and `power` are all 0, and you never change them-- therefore you're executing your `while` loop (and therefore your `for` loop) an infinite number of times.

Why do you have that while loop there at all?

Comment: the while-loop should probably be changed to an if-clause?

Comment: @FlorianMinges I really can't tell what OP is going for-- wouldn't you want to print the sequence regardless?

Comment: I was under the impression that the system.in assigned the user input to those variables?

Comment: System.out just prints the parameters to the console.

Comment: @user2057847 it does-- I was assuming that for testing purposes (as you said this code is incomplete), you fed in 0s for all 3. Is that not true? If not, please post exactly what test values you're using.

Comment: Thanks Florian Minges, that fixed it.

Comment: @user2057847 sorry, what fixed it?

Comment: I made the mistake of using "while" to test the variables, but since they never actually updated it was giving an infinite loop.

Comment: @user2057847 oh, ok, so *my* comment, not Florian's. In that case, answer credit, please? :)

Answer (score 0):

You never, ever, change the values of multi, divi or power. How do you expect the while to end if those values never change?